# Pass optional arguments to superclass

Tags: ruby, oop, inheritance

```
module MyModule
  class Parent
    def initialize(a, b=nil)
      begin 
        @my_var = b[:some_key]
      rescue
        @my_var = {}
      end
    end
  end
end

module MyModule
  class Child < Parent
    def initialize(a, b=nil)
      super a, b
      begin 
        @my_var = b[:some_key]
      rescue
        @my_var = {:some_key => 'something more specific'}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I have two classes, that I'm basically using begin / rescue / end to set an optional parameter as an instance variable.  I KNOW that I'm using exception handling for control flow here, I just don't know another way!  How can I set `@my_var` to either itself (non-nil) or an empty hash?

I've tried...

```
def initialize(a, b=nil)
  b ||= {}
  super
end
```

I guess my main problem is I don't understand how optional args and `super` work?  Does the fact that I'm inheriting within a module change anything?

Comment: I should add that my intention is for `b` to basically be an options hash, through which multiple instance vars are set in the Parent class.

Comment: have you tried `initialize(a, b={})`?

Comment: This is definitely a 'smack yourself in the forehead with your palm' moment.  Thanks, @UriAgassi!  If you answer instead of commenting, I can accept it.

Comment: `@my_var` is also being assigned with two different types of objects in your `begin` and `rescue` blocks.

Comment: To address your issue of having to use rescue, try using fetch instead. http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Hash/fetch

my_var = b.fetch(:some_key,{})
my_var = b.fetch(:some_key, {:some_key => 'something more specific'})

Comment: @konsolebox, that's sort of what I want, and why I was doing it through a `begin` block, so I can handle the typeError if the hash doesn't exist yet.  Pretttyyyy sure this isn't the best way to do it.

Comment: @JeffPrice, thanks, trying that.  Is that basically the equivalent of this:

`some_hash = {}`
`some_hash[:foo] || 'bar'`

Comment: Have you considered `.nil?`, `.is_a? Hash`, `.has_key?()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value is used if no parameter is passed, so you can use a different default value for the child and parent (since `super` explicitly passes the optional parameter).

Actually (as @CarySwoveland has commented) you don't even have to write the parameters to `super`, since writing `super` without parameters implicitly passes the original parameters.:

```
module MyModule
  class Parent
    def initialize(a, b={})
      @my_var = b[:some_key]
    end
     attr_accessor :my_var
  end
end

module MyModule
  class Child < Parent
    def initialize(a, b={some_key: 'something more specific'})
      super
    end
  end
end 

MyModule::Parent.new('a').my_var
# => nil 
MyModule::Child.new('a').my_var
# => "something more specific"
```

In ruby versions of 2.0 onwards, you could use [Keyword Arguments](http://brainspec.com/blog/2012/10/08/keyword-arguments-ruby-2-0/) to do the same thing more expressively:

```
module MyModule
  class Parent
    def initialize(a, some_key: nil)
      @my_var = some_key
    end
     attr_accessor :my_var
  end
end

module MyModule
  class Child < Parent
    def initialize(a, some_key: 'something more specific')
      super
    end
  end
end
```